# View Column Headers Fixed Using XPages

Tags: xpages

I need one help related to view panel column headers. I am using view panel to pull the data from SQL using JDBC Connection manager and displaying in view panel control using Xpages. I am displaying 500 rows at a time and when users trying to scroll the data the column headers are going scrolling up. So, now I need to fix all view column header should be fixed when the rows are scrolling up/down. Can anybody help me regarding this?

Answer (score 2):

You can add that capability to an existing `viewPanel` with the [jQuery.Thead](http://mkoryak.github.io/floatThead) plugin. There are only 2 steps involved:

- Download the library and add it to your XPage/ application.
- Activate the plugin for your viewPanel (or repeat):

`x$("#{id:viewPanel1}").floatThead({});`

(the x$ function comes from the ExtLib Bootstrap theme)

I've put together a small demo here:

http://bootstrap4xpages.com/bs4xp/demos.nsf/fixedHeaders.xsp

Comment: Looks Nice Mark!

Comment: Hello Mark, thanks for your answer for my above question. Can you please clarify a) I have downloaded the plugin and I have seen two JS files, whether I need to use both js files? b) do I need to use these js files as client side script libraries? Could you please little bit detail about which even I need to call the jquery function (x$("#{id:viewPanel1}").floatThead({});) to invoke in my xpage? I have seen some css also in your demo, do I need to use those css also in my application?

Comment: I am getting the below exception when I am trying to use this Jquery function into my Xpages for both client side and server side script using onClientLoad even in my xpages. I think I am sure that something I am missing over here.

Comment: Error source
Page Name:/xpPartInfoOverview.xsp
Control Id: _id1
Property: onClientLoad


Exception
Error while executing JavaScript action expression
Script interpreter error, line=1, col=1: [ReferenceError] 'x$' not found

JavaScript code


   1: x$("#{id:viewPanel1}").floatThead({});

Comment: The 'x$' error is probably because you're not using the Bootstrap ExtLib theme. You don't have to use that, but jQuery.floatThead requires jQuery, so you need to add that as a minimum and can then also use a different selector (for example: set the `dataTableStyleClass` attribute on your viewPanel and then use $('.yourClass'). About your other questions: a) no, just pick 1 from the 'dist' folder. b) yes. The CSS I added to the demo isn't required. BTW: the full XPage source here can be view here: https://github.com/markleusink/Bootstrap4XPages/blob/master/Demos/XPages/fixedHeaders.xsp.

Comment: After loading all these libraries I am getting the below error:Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'floatThead' of undefined
    at $ (jquery.floatThead.js&jquery.floatThead.min.js:21)
    at jquery.floatThead.js&jquery.floatThead.min.js:1100
dojo.js:15 ReferenceError: x$ is not defined
    at view__id1__id48_clientSide_onClientLoad (xpPartInfoOverview.xsp:7624)
    at _3.x_dfe [as _doFireEvent] (@Jt&@Iq.js:271)
    at _3.x_fe [as fireEvent] (@Jt&@Iq.js:271)
    at xaep_fpre (@Jt&@Iq.js:271)
    at _3.x_aep [as _attachEventOrPartial] (@Jt&@Iq.js:271)
    a

Comment: Without looking at the looking at the code you're using and what libraries you included, it's hard to tell. Remember that you only need one of the files from the floatThead dist folder.

Comment: After, I enabled the bootstrap4 theme I am getting the error as 
Bootstrap tooltips require Tether (http://github.hubspot.com/tether/) while debugging the code. Can you please let me know if I am missing something more here?

Answer (score 1):

May be have a look at DataTables, for details to implement this in XPages see the blogs ofOliver Busse, http://oliverbusse.notesx.net/hp.nsf/blogpost.xsp?documentId=D5E

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way will be to add viewStyle to your viewPanel and set it to 100%.

[image]

I hope this helps!